# Nested binary Search Java

Tags: java, binary, binary-search

In Java in one of case I have an list of Parent class I defined. This Parent class have object of Child class and this Child class contain search-variable.

Now Is there any way to perform search for nested class-variable.
Basically I just wanted to confirm if Parent-Class-List contain that Child-Class-Search variable or not.

```
ArrayList<Parent> parentList;

class Parent {

    Child child;
}

class Child {
    String searchVariable;
}
```

Any Suggestion!

Comment: What are you asking? You want to check if all `Parent`s have a child with a search variable? Or if at least one of them does? Or if all that have a child have a child with a searchvariabe? How is "contain" defined, does the search variable have to be non-null or non-empty? What have you tried?

Comment: How many parent contain Child-search value and if they does who are they. I tried with Collections.binarySearch(parentList, new Child().search) with comparator interface...I guess it will work.

Comment: Use [Collections.binarySearch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch-java.util.List-T-java.util.Comparator-) with your own Comparator implementation comparing child.searchVariable.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this shall do the job:

```
declare child list: childrenWithSearchVar ;
for(Parent p : parentList) {
   if(p.child.searhVariable!=null && !p.child.searhVariable.equals("")) {
         add to childrenWithSearchVar 
   }
}
print childrenWithSearchVar
```